# Postback Contains No Model Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that was not receiving any of my model information on the postback.  I have tried to comment out more and more to make it simple so I can see when it works and so far I am having no luck.  I have commented out most of the complex parts of the form and model so I do not know why I am having issues.

Below is the controller functions to show the form and to post it

```
public ActionResult MassEmail()
    {
        IEmailTemplateRepository templates = new EmailTemplateRepository();
        IEmailFromAddressRepository froms = new EmailFromAddressRepository();
        IEmployeeRepository emps = new EmployeeRepository();
        List<ProductVersion> vers = new List<ProductVersion>();
        MassEmailViewModel vm = new MassEmailViewModel();

        vers = productVersionRepository.All.OrderBy(o => o.Description).ToList();

        foreach (Employee e in emps.Employees.Where(o => o.Department == "Support" || o.Department == "Professional Services").OrderBy(o => o.Name))
        {
            if (e.Email != null && e.Email.Trim() != "")
            {
                vm.BCCAddresses = vm.BCCAddresses + e.Email + ","; 
            }
        }
        if (vm.BCCAddresses != "")
        {
            vm.BCCAddresses = vm.BCCAddresses.Substring(0, vm.BCCAddresses.Length - 1);
        }

        ViewBag.PossibleCustomers = customerRepository.All.OrderBy(o => o.CustomerName);
        ViewBag.PossibleTemplates = templates.All.OrderBy(o => o.Description);
        ViewBag.PossibleFromAddresses = froms.All.OrderBy(o => o.Description);
        ViewBag.PossibleClasses = scheduledClassRepository.All.OrderByDescending(o => o.ClassDate).ThenBy(o => o.ClassTopic.Description);

        vm.CCAddresses = "bclairmont@harrisworld.com";
        //vm.Attachments = "";
        vm.Body = "";
        vm.Subject = "";
        vm.ToAddresses = "";
        vm.EmailFromAddressID = 1;

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MassEmail(MassEmailViewModel vm)
    {
        IEmailFromAddressRepository froms = new EmailFromAddressRepository();

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(froms.Find(vm.EmailFromAddressID).Email);

        string[] toAddresses = vm.ToAddresses.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < toAddresses.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toAddresses[i]));
        }

        string[] CCAddresses = vm.CCAddresses.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < CCAddresses.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(CCAddresses[i]));
        }

        string[] BCCAddresses = vm.BCCAddresses.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < BCCAddresses.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(BCCAddresses[i]));
        }
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = vm.Subject; 
        message.Body = vm.Body;

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName));
        }

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);

        return RedirectToAction("MassEmail");
    }
```

Next is the code for my View

```
@model TRIOSoftware.WebUI.Models.MassEmailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MassEmail";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h1 class="align-right">Mass E-Mail</h1>

    <br />
    <br />

 <div>
<div class="editor-label" style="float:left; width:90px">
    From
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="float:left">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmailFromAddressID,   
((IEnumerable<TRIOSoftware.Domain.Entities.EmailFromAddress>)
ViewBag.PossibleFromAddresses).OrderBy(m => m.Description).Select(option => new 
SelectListItem
{
   Text = option.Description.ToString(),
   Value = option.ID.ToString(),
   Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ID == Model.EmailFromAddressID)
}), "Choose...")  
</div>
</div>

<div class= "TagitEmailAddress" style="width:100%">
<div class="editor-label" style="float:left; clear:left;  width:90px">
    To
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="float:left; width:88%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToAddresses, new { @class = "TagTextBox" })
</div>
</div>

<div class= "TagitEmailAddress" style="width:100%">
<div class="editor-label" style="float:left; clear:left; width:90px">
    CC
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="float:left; width:88%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CCAddresses, new { @class = "TagTextBox" })
</div>
</div>

<div class= "TagitEmailAddress" style="width:100%">
<div class="editor-label" style="float:left; clear:left; width:90px">
    <input type="button" id="BCC" value="BCC" class="btn"/>
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="float:left; width:88%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BCCAddresses, new { @class = "TagTextBox" })
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%">
<div style="float:left; clear:left; width:90px">
    <input type="button" id="Subject" value="Subject" class="btn"/>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:88%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new { id = "SubjectText", style =  
    "width:100%" })
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%">
<div style="clear:left; float:left; width:100%;">
    <div class="editor-field" style="float:left; width:100%;">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { id = "BodyText" })
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<p style="clear:both">
    <input type="submit" value="Send E-Mail" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</p>

<div id="DefaultEmailText">
<div class="editor-label" style="float:left; width:150px">
    E-Mail Template
</div>
<div class="editor-field" style="float:left; padding-left:10px">
    @Html.DropDownList("EmailTemplate",  
   ((IEnumerable<TRIOSoftware.Domain.Entities.EmailTemplate>)
   ViewBag.PossibleTemplates).Select(option => new SelectListItem
   {
       Text = option.Description,
       Value = option.ID.ToString(),
       Selected = false
   }), "Choose...", new { ID = "Template", style = "width:200px" })    
</div>
</div>
}

@section sidemenu {
    @Html.Action("EmailsSideMenu", "Admin")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var TemplateSubject = "";
var TemplateBody = "";

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#attach').MultiFile({
        STRING: {
            remove: '<i style="color:Red" class="icon-remove-sign"></i>'
        }
    }); 

    $(".TagTextBox").tagit();

    $("#BodyText").cleditor({
        width: 800,
        height: 400
    });

    $("#DefaultEmailText").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 150,
        width: 250,
        title: "Default Subject / Body",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK: function () {
                var selectedTemplate = $("#DefaultEmailText #Template").val();
                if (selectedTemplate != null && selectedTemplate != '') {
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetTemplate", "EmailTemplates")', { id: 
                      selectedTemplate }, function (template) {
                        $("#SubjectText").val(template[0].Subject);
                        $("#BodyText").val(template[0].Body).blur(); 
                    });
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#Subject').click(function () {
        $("#DefaultEmailText").dialog("open");
    });


});

</script>
```

When I submit I get all null values except for the EmailFromAddressID which is 0 even though ti gets defaulted ot 1 when the view loads.

Any ideas?

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**
I looked in DevConsole of Chrome and under network I coudl see my post request.  Below is the detailed informaiton it contained.  It looks to me liek the data did get sent to the server so I do not knwo why the server cant fill in my Model class

```
Request URL:http://localhost:53730/Customers/MassEmail
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost:53730
Referer:http://localhost:53730/Customers/MassEmail
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17

Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
EmailFromAddressID:1
ToAddresses:
CCAddresses:bclairmont@harrisworld.com
BCCAddresses:adunn@harrisworld.com,bclairmont@harrisworld.com,
bkelly@harrisworld.com,bhackett@harrisworld.com,jwade@harrisworld.com,
krichter@harrisworld.com,mroy-waters@harrisworld.com,
nburckhard@harrisworld.com,rlibby@harrisworld.com
Subject:Testing
Body:
```

Here is the class that gets passed back and forth from the clien tto server in case that helps

```
public class MassEmailViewModel
{
    //public MassEmailViewModel()
    //{
    //    ComplexQuery = new CustomerQueryViewModel(); 
    //}

    public int EmailFromAddressID;

   // public CustomerQueryViewModel ComplexQuery;

    public string ToAddresses;
    public string CCAddresses;
    public string BCCAddresses;
    public string Subject;
    public string Body;
    //public string Attachments;
}
```

Comment: id field is posted back as 0 since its integer which cannot be null. and it has a default value of 0.

Comment: You should check your POST request in DevConsole (IE and Chrome F12) or FireBug or fiddler and check which data is gets sent to the server.

Comment: I did check the DevConsole and posted the results above.  It looks like the data is getting passed so I guess that means that the probelm is that it isnt filling in the class with the data that was passed back automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` needs **public properties** not public fields.

Change your fields to properties and it should work:

```
public class MassEmailViewModel
{
    public int EmailFromAddressID { get; set; }

    public string ToAddresses { get; set; }
    public string CCAddresses { get; set; }
    public string BCCAddresses { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You were right.  I changed them to properties and i worked.  I guess I a a little confused though.  All of my other views are based on the same type of classes although those are tied to EF.  Why in those classes o I not need to declare things as properties?  Does being tied to EF have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you tried specifing the route of the controller to which the model will be submited?. I mean, declaring the form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController", FormMethod.Post))
```

2) Why dont you just create a simple "Get" action that returns the strongly typed view and a "Post" action that receives the same model with the information you added in the view. Once you make work that, you can begin adding extra code so it is easy to trobleshoot the problem.

3) Make sure all of your helpers are inside the form.

4) Have you configured routing rules that can be making your post being redirected to another area, controller or action?

Comment: I did try to specify the route in my form and I got the sema results.  I knwo it is being posted ot the corect route because I have a breakpoint in the beginning of rthe post routine on the controller and it gos there.  I just have no data in the class.  I can even see that th actual data gets passed to the controllr in the request object it just doesnt translate into my class.

Comment: I guess I don't see the difference in the get routine you suggest and what I am doing.  I have the the normal controller function that returns my strongly typed view so I do not understand why the data does not translate back to the class on the post method.